# How to fetch Primary Key/Clustering column names for a particular table using CQL statements?

Tags: cassandra, cql, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to fetch the Primary Key/Clustering Key names for a particular table/entity and implement the same query in my JPA interface (which extends CassandraRepository).
I am not sure whether something like:

```
@Query("DESCRIBE TABLE <table_name>)
public Object describeTbl();
```

would work here as `describe` isn't a valid CQL statement and in case it would, what would be the type of the `Object`?

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could try, would be to query the `system_schema.columns` table.  It is keyed by `keyspace_name` and `table_name`, and might be what you're looking for here:

```
> SELECT column_name,kind FROM system_schema.columns
  WHERE keyspace_name='spaceflight_data'
  AND table_name='astronauts_by_group';

 column_name       | kind
-------------------+---------------
           flights |       regular
             group | partition_key
              name |    clustering
 spaceflight_hours |    clustering

(4 rows)
```

Comment: This is more like the answer I was looking for. +1

Comment: the main problem is that there are differences in schema between Cassandra 2 & 3, and driver abstracts that difference

Answer (score 1):

`DESCRIBE TABLE` is supported only in Cassandra 4 that includes fix for [CASSANDRA-14825](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14825).  But it may not help you much because it just returns the text string representing the `CREATE TABLE` statement, and you'll need to parse text to extract primary key definition - it's doable but could be tricky, depending on the structure of the primary key.

Or you can obtain underlying `Session` object and via `getMetadata` function get access to actual [metadata object](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.13/manual/core/metadata/) that allows to obtain information about keyspaces & tables, including the information about schema.